# Property for referencing the assembly directory?

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

When using the assembly plugin, it seems like there should be a property exposed, such as ${assembly.directory}, by which you could reference the assembly output directory.  By assembly output directory, I mean the directory in which the assembly plugin puts the assembly it creates for you; in my case, I'm creating a "dir" type assembly so the output directory is the assembly itself.  In my usage of the assembly plugin, the "directory output assembly" turns out to be something like:

```
${project.build.directory}/${artifactId}-${project.version}/${artifactId}-${project.version}
```

But that is obviously kind of a nasty thing to write out in all of the places I need to reference the assembly output location.  I would prefer something like

```
${project.assembly.outputDirectory}
```

Here's my assembly plugin config:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>assemble-myStuff</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                            <descriptors>
                                <descriptor>src/main/assemble/myAssembly.xml</descriptor>
                            </descriptors>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "assembly directory" ? Do you mean the directory where by default the results will be stored or do you mean the directory where descriptors will be found? May be you can give an example pom which describes your problem better?

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand you correct but that sound like assembly-descriptors what you need or may be component descriptors...but the problem is why do you need to define the directory in that way. ? May be you can give an pom which defines what you like to achieve as an example...BTW: The maven-assembly-plugin has a newer version 2.3 available.

Comment: Or do you mean the outputDirectory of the assembly-plugin ?

Comment: I do mean the ouptput directory.  And my issue is not configuring the assembly plugin, it's referencing the place that the assembly plugin put the assembly it built . . .

Comment: Hm. Than i don't see a way. But why do you need this information. The ${project.build.directory} is used in outputDirectory as default by the plugin configuration so the question is why do you need that itself? (That sounds like a cyclic dependency ;-)

Comment: I have a process that builds a binary installer; I run it with the maven exec plugin.  The builder pulls the assembly when it builds my binary installer.

Comment: Can you say which installer this is?

Comment: It's a Bitrock installer.  We produce the installer binary, then deploy that as an "attached" artifact.  It works nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But that is obviously kind of a nasty thing to write out in all of the places I need to reference the assembly output location.

True, but I don't think the plugin will provide it for you.  I had a similar issue and solved it this way (not ideal, but hey):

```
<properties>
   <myAssemblyOutput>${project.build.directory}/${artifactId}-${project.version}/${artifactId}-${project.version}</myAssemblyOutput>
</properties>
```

And use ${myAssemblyOutput} throughout.

Comment: I was suspecting that was the best I could do.  I just wondered if there might be undocumented properties exposed by the mojo somehow.